# The ECC private key is generated with 0x00 at the beginning.(prefix)

Tags: elliptic-curves

I created a private key using the prime256v1 curve.
My purpose is to get a 32 byte private key.
However, the private key is preceded by 0x00, resulting in 33 bytes.
Why is this happening?
The only space I can use is 32 bytes.

Comment: [It's probably the "version" of the private key format used.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84331/71460)

Comment: My openssl version is 1.0.1